# How to use language selector of LoginPage component of Patternfly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, patternfly

How can I use the language selector (number 2 at image) of Patternfly [`LoginPage`](https://www.patternfly.org/v4/components/login-page/design-guidelines/#elements) component?

[image]

At docs, the language selector dropdown appears in all the examples. However I can't figure out how to use it. I guess there should exist a property on `LoginPage` to render it but I can't find it.

I have checked [the list of properties in the own code](https://github.com/patternfly/patternfly-react/blob/main/packages/react-core/src/components/LoginPage/LoginPage.tsx#L15) too, with no luck.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what's the problem you face? is the dropdown not working or do you want to know how to connect it to translations?

Comment: I want to use the language selector of `LoginPage` component. It appears at docs but I cant find instructions on how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that `LoginPage` React component property `languageSelector` has been **removed** from Patternfly. Docs are outdated.

Got [following response](https://github.com/patternfly/patternfly-react/issues/7228#issuecomment-1162526092) in the github repository issues section:

> Yes, I believe this had been removed a while ago as
> we were working through some design issues. However you can see a core
> HTML example that includes the language selector here:
> https://www.patternfly.org/v4/components/login-page/html#with-language-selector

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://zen-swanson-2d3350.netlify.app/components/loginpage/) you can find full example, with code example and all available props described.

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereI think they just help you with design you should do the rest

Use i18n to translate. https://react.i18next.com/latest/using-with-hooks

Try this https://lokalise.com/blog/how-to-internationalize-react-application-using-i18next/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know how to use `react-i18next`. I just want to use the patternfly language selector component to integrate it.

Comment: They are just dropdown lists so you can use click events to get the selected language then change translation like ```const handleOnclick=(e)=>{
   e.preventDefault();
   setLanguage(e.target.value);
   i18n.changeLanguage(e.target.value);
 }```

Comment: https://locize.com/blog/how-to-internationalize-react-i18next/#language-switcher